# SQL Server trigger with EF TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers, transactionscope

Can anyone help me with problem with trigger on insert/update when inserting records to tables in a SQL Server database using EF and `TransactionScope`?

When I try the trigger in SQL Server Management Studio, it's working fine, also the app is working fine when there is no trigger or trigger is disabled.

I have 2 SQL Server tables, `Orders` and `OrdersParts`. I have a trigger on `OrdersParts` that I use to update another table based calculations of inserted records.

Is any workaround so I can make something in SQL Server trigger because I don't want to change the code?

Thank you...

Here is my code in VS, I get fail in repository.CreateOrder

```
 public void CreateOrder(Guid userId, int? referenceId, Cart cart, OrderInfo orderInfo)
        {
            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                var order = new Orders
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    ReferenceId = referenceId,
                    Status = (int)OrderStatus.Created,
                    PaymentType = (int)orderInfo.PaymentType,
                    ShippingType = orderInfo.ShippingType,
                    Comment = orderInfo.Comment,
                    DateTimeCreated = DateTime.Now
                };
                context.Orders.Add(order);
                context.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var line in cart.Lines)
                {
                    context.OrdersParts.Add(new OrdersParts
                    {
                        PartId = line.Product.ProductId,
                        OrderId = order.OrderId,
                        Price = line.Product.Price,
                        Quantity = line.Quantity
                    });
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Complete();

            }
        }
```

Here is My CreateOrder HTTP Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateOrder(Cart cart, OrderInfo orderInfo)
        {
            var result = new JsonResult<bool>() { Status = true };

            var user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            var userId = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;

            try
            {                

                var userDetails = usersRepository.Members.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
                if (!userDetails.ClientId.HasValue)
                {
                    result.Status = false;
                    result.Result = false;
                    result.Message = "Errror Client";
                    return Json(result);
                }
                int clientId = userDetails.ClientId.Value;

                // Create order in WareHouse
                string message = null;
                int? referenceId;


                if (!integrationService.CreateOrder(clientId, cart, orderInfo, out referenceId, out message))
                {
                    result.Status = false;
                    result.Result = false;
                    result.Message = message;
                    return Json(result);
                }

                repository.CreateOrder(userId, referenceId, cart, orderInfo);
                cart.Clear();

                result.Result = true;
                result.Message = "";
            }
            catch
            {
                result.Status = false;
                result.Result = false;
                result.Message = "Error on creating order! Please try again.";
            }

            return Json(result);
        }
```

Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateComment] ON [dbo].[OrdersParts]
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @OrderID INT;
        DECLARE @QDefWareH INT;
        DECLARE @OrderedQuantity INT;
        DECLARE @ArticleID VARCHAR(20);


        DECLARE my_Cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
        FOR
            SELECT  a.OrderId ,
                    a.Quantity ,
                    b.RefSifra
            FROM    INSERTED a
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Accounting b ON b.PartId = a.PartId;

        OPEN my_Cursor; 
        FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor INTO @OrderID, @OrderedQuantity, @ArticleID;

        EXEC @QDefWareH = _SPArtInDefWarehouse @ArticleID;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN 

                SELECT  @QDefWareH;

                IF ( @OrderedQuantity > @QDefWareH )
                    BEGIN

                        UPDATE  dbo.Orders
                        SET     Comment = IIF(Comment IS NULL, @ArticleID, Comment
                                + ' ;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @ArticleID)
                        WHERE   OrderId = @OrderID;
                    END;    

                FETCH NEXT FROM my_Cursor INTO @OrderID, @OrderedQuantity,
                    @ArticleID;
            END;

        CLOSE my_Cursor;
        DEALLOCATE my_Cursor;

    END;
```

Comment: What is going wrong when the trigger is enabled?

Comment: @Crowcoder the code fails on transaction.Complete(); and only the record in Order table is inserted bit not the records in OrdersParts

Comment: And the exception details are...?

Comment: Here is Controller Http Post Method inserted in Question!

Comment: It would be more useful to see the trigger definition and exception details.

Comment: Update your question with exception details

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft question updated with trigger defenition

Comment: Here, the issue is you are updating Order table in Trigger before the transaction is completed. So, to fix this - mention IsolationLevel in TransactionScope.

Comment: And the exception details are ...?

Comment: Remove the statement "SELECT  @QDefWareH;" from the trigger. Triggers should not return resultsets. Your left join in the cursor is highly suspicious since the unpreserved table (Accounting) provides a key piece of information - which your code  assumes is not null. The variable @QDefWareH is never used so why call the stored proc? I'd say you still have some work to do on the trigger. Try testing it **thoroughly.**